# Dynamics 365 Customers Insights - Journey, Not able to register web application to use the events API

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to create a web application to use Event API from Dynamics Customer Insights - Journey where I'm trying to register it as mentioned in the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-insights/journeys/developer/register-web-application-events-api

Issue is, I'm not able to find Advance Settings Option under Settings as mentioned in Step 3,
[image]

Instead I'm getting below mentioned Options:
[image]